# How to revert packages to official release?

Tags: official-repositories

Ubuntu 13.10, I have added test repo and upgraded system. Now not everything is working correctly. How to revert packages to official release versions?

Comment: Which repo did you add? Is it a PPA?

Comment: See the second most popular answer(the firs will only remove the ppa line from your sources) talking about PPA-purge http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed

Comment: I added ppa:mc3man/sacy-tests repo to enable skype tray icon.

Answer (score 0):

Firs you need to remove the skype that is installed from the PPA.

```
sudo apt-get remove skype
```

Then should remove the PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/sacy-tests
```

After this, you need to update the package details by updating.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install skype from Official repository.

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```